# How do you format python code for competitive programming?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a python3 coder, and am trying to get into competitive programming through websites like Codeforces. I am not sure how to write functions that are accepted by the website though. I can solve problems just fine, but I keep getting errors and I don't know how to submit my answer. Are you meant to create some function? There is no template to use so I have an answer but no way to submit it. 
For example,
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/977/A
This problem is fairly simple, and I wrote this answer that works in my terminal:

```
def tanya(n, k):
    for i in range(k):
        last = n % 10
        if last == 0:
            n = n/10
        else:
            n = n - 1
    return int(n)
```

but I am completely unable to submit it in the website. It keeps giving me runtime errors, even though I know my code works fine. I am just wondering how python code needs to be formatted to be accepted by websites like CodeForces or the USACO. Thanks for any help

Comment: What are the errors? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like input is provided in `stdin` and output should be written to `stdout`, so your solution should look like that:

```py
n, k = input().split()
n = int(n)
k = int(k)

for i in range(k):
    last = n % 10
    if last == 0:
        n = n/10
    else:
        n = n - 1
print(int(n))
```

**Note:** I didn't check your solution, just rewrote it in simplest way to illustrate the method.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to get the input or output, and your solution worked